# How to run an equation along whole column in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run an excel vba which will go down column E and upon finding the value = "capa" will go two cell below, calculate the hex2dec value of that cell, present it by the cell with the value "capa" in column F and continue to search down column E.
So far I've came with the below but it doesn't work:

```
 For Each cell In Range("E:E")
     If cell.Value = "Capa" Then
           ActiveCell.Offset.FormulaR1C1 = "=HEX2DEC(R[2]C[-1])"
     End If
Next cell
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

This will search volumn E for "Capa" and, if found, will place formula in column F using the value directly below "Capa" in column E

```
Sub CapaSearch()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Range("E:E")
        If cl.Value = "Capa" Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=HEX2DEC(" & cl.Offset(1, 0) & ")"
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want to limit the loop so you don't loop over the whole sheet (1,000,000+ rows in Excel 2007+)
Also, copying the source data to a variant array will speed things up too.

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        dat = .Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1)
            If dat(i, 6 - .Column) = "Capa" Then
                .Cells(i, 7 - .Column).FormulaR1C1 = "=HEX2DEC(R[2]C[-1])"
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```